# Expanding RAID 1 array size (Adaptec 1420SA controller)

Tags: raid, adaptec, expansion

I have an [Adaptec 1420SA controller](http://www.adaptec.com/en-us/support/raid/sataii/aar-1420sa/) in server and RAID 1 array created. The old disks slowly started to report S.M.A.R.T errors so I replaced first one, rebuild array and then other one and rebuild the array again. But the new drives are bigger, so I'd like to expand the array to use full disk capacity.

Is it somehow possible? In the Adaptec configuration utility, after POST, I didn't found anything that could do it.

I still have the old drives, if it helps. The array is used for system (Windows 2008 R2 SP1) booting.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adaptec support just send me a response and on this controller it's not available.

Answer (score 0):

If you simply swap out a single existing dead/dying disk member from a R1 array with a larger disk it will simply ignore any extra space over the original disk, even if you then switch out the second disk member for the same disk - i.e. the R1 array will remain at that size regardless of whether replacement disks are larger or not.

Obviously if you build a new array with the larger disks it will be the larger size.

Comment: I know that. But some controllers allow you to expand the R1 size when you put larger drives into array. I'm trying to find a way to do the same with this controller.